# Javascript - array problems

Tags: javascript, arrays

For my school project i am trying to get a users data and then display them in a table.

My code is :

**Javascript**

```
    var array =Array();//fname
    var array1 =Array(); //lname 

function a(){
    let fname = document.getElementById("Fname").value;
    let lname = document.getElementById("Lname").value;

    array.push(''+fname);
    array1.push(''+lname);}

function moriodotisi() {
    var ttable = $('#t01');
    ttable.empty();
    ttable.append('' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th>Name</th>' +
        '<th>LastName</th>' +
        '</tr>'
    );
    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        ttable.append(''+
        '<tr>' +
        '<th>'+array[y]+'</th>' +
        '<th>'+array1[y]+'</th>' +
        '</tr>'
        );
    }
}
```

I think this supposed to look like 
Name            LastName
MyName       MyLastName

But it is like 
Name LastName
M M
y y
N L
a a
m s
e t
..... etc

Also i am using the same array in a different function ant it works and displays the whole word not letter by letter...
the other function is :

```
function display_array() {
    var cards_container = $('#cards-container');
    cards_container.empty();
    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        cards_container.append('' +
            '<div class="table-responsive">' +

            '<table class="table">' +
            '   <thead>' +
            '     <tr>' +
            '       <th>Firstname</th>' +
            '       <th>Lastname</th>' 
            '     </tr>' +
            '   </thead>' +
            '   <tbody>' +
            '     <tr>' +
            '       <td >' + array[y] + '</td>' +
            '       <td>' + array1[y] + '</td>' 
            '     </tr>' +
            '   </tbody>' +
            ' </table>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you're facing is that the variables `array` and `array1` are of type 'string' and are not arrays. The reason why you're not getting an error is that within strings, you can also use the index to access a character. So with the code string `const text = 'hello'`, then accessing the elements as if it's an array, such as `text[1]  //'e'` will produce the character in that spot.

As to your code, I cannot see where the variables `array` and `array1` are redefined to be a string, but there are a number of ways those variables may become a string between the time you defined them (or when `a` is called) to when the function `moriodotisi` is called. I suspect you have somewhere some code that looks like this `array = document.getElementById("Fname").value`.

To advice on where specifically your bug is, I'd need to see more code, but from what I've said above, it should be enough to track down the issue.
I'd recommend placing some `console.log('')` calls to follow `array` as you run the script.

Comment: Well i need to use the same javascript file in many html pages and i couldnt find a way to make the arrays static , to keep all values. Then i found that i can (kind of) do that by : 
 localStorage.setItem("array", array);
 localStorage.setItem("array1", array1);
And then "get those values " by 
var array = localStorage.getItem("array");
var array1 = localStorage.getItem("array1");

Comment: @cdg, saving localStorage seems issue. you will need to stringify while set and need to JSON parse after getting.  `localStorage.setItem("array", JSON.stringify(array))` and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array"))`.

Comment: @cdg Using localstorage is a bit of a messy solution. Since it's a school project it will be fine in my opinion, if it works then it will be okay. 
I'd recommend looking up how to make Single page apps, using frameworks such as React or Angular. This way you can navigate between pages but not have to reload scripts, this allow you to keep the state the same between pages.
https://reactjs.org/